# Jupyter notebook disablle or change password

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, credentials

I am trying to re-use an old jupyter notebook that runs through a server. However, I have forgotten my password. I am trying to reset it by using the following:

```
jupyter notebook password
```

that creates a hashed password at ashed password at:

> /.../.../.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json

When I check this file it contains the following:

```
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "password": 

        "argon2:$argon2id$v=1... ..."
  }
 }
```

So I guess I need to cp this password to my  `jupyter_notebook_config.py` that is located in the same direction that I run my `jupyter notebook`. I add the following in this document:

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.NotebookApp.custom_display_url = 'https://...my_url...'
c.NotebookApp.password = "argon2:$argon2id$v=1... ..."
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '127.0.0.1' 
c.NotebookApp.password_required = True
c.NotebookApp.port = 8080
```

However, the password does not work and I keep getting invalid credentials message. I have multiple questions. Firstly, am I doing something wrong here? Secondly, is there a chance that there can be a conflict in  `jupyter_notebook_config.py` files? Is there a chance that sees another file instead of the one that is located in the directory? Is there a way to disable completely the password setting?

**EDIT:**

I have followed the recommendations from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-disable-the-password-request-for-a-Jupyter-Notebook-session) but still while I can see when I run `jupyter notebook` a message that says that All authentication is disabled when I am trying to access remotely the notebook still it asks me for a pass (which I do not remember :))

Comment: If you can still access the notebook file (which I think you can), just uninstall and  reinstall jupyter, and this time write your password somewhere safe.

Comment: But then, should I create a sha1 or argon2 pass? I do not have a clue what needs to be the correct thingy.

Comment: do whatever the default is.  That's a good rule with security, *always*, if you don't know what you're doing.  Though sha1 is quite bad, I'm surprised it's even being suggested.  (but still **do whatever is default**)

Comment: Ok then I am creating a pass with jupyter notebook password and it is store in json file which I need to cp to my configuration file (the argon2 pass). But still, it does not work (after re-installing jupyter).

Comment: delete (/move) your *whole* installation, and reinstall jupyter from scratch (follow one of the tutorials).  then when you have jupyter running properly, load your notebook file (which you do have, right?!).

Comment: It is also weird that I cannot disable the password when I am setting c.NotebookApp.password_required = False. Still it is asking forit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237447/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-jose-ramon).